# Call User defined function as System Function in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

I have created an user defined functions in SQL server. Is it possible to call these function in select statement, just like any other built-in function?

```
Create function [dbo].[TIME_TO_SEC](@inputTime time)
returns INT
As
Begin 
    DECLARE @secDiff INT = datediff(second, '00:00:00', @inputTime)
    return @secDiff;
end
```

Currently calling this as below:

```
DECLARE @ret int;
EXEC TIME_TO_SEC @inputTime='01:00:00'
select @ret;
```

I am attempting something as simple as:

```
select TIME_TO_SEC('01:00:00') from TimeTable
```

Is it feasible in SQL-server?

Comment: Yes you can call a scalar function as a part of SELECT query. And you can pass column as a parameter if needed

Comment: What actually happened when you tried selecting that function as you described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but you need to reference the function by the user's schema

```
select dbo.TIME_TO_SEC('01:00:00') from TimeTable
```

Answer (score 1):

if you get an issue with your function, try to add "WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER"

```
Create function [dbo].[TIME_TO_SEC](@inputTime time)
Returns int
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
As
Begin 
    DECLARE @secDiff INT = datediff(second, '00:00:00', @inputTime)
    return @secDiff;
end
```

then call the function with select

```
select  dbo.[TIME_TO_SEC](getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's certainly feasible, and it looks like you've got everything you need already.  Have you tried it?